# (javaScript: DOM) setAttribute index

Tags: javascript, dom, setattribute

I'm trying to add  an image inside `<img>` through javaScript DOM and just wondering why the first code works but second code doesn't work? Why does `img` need an index?

```
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    img[0].setAttribute("src", "images/image_1.jpg");
    img[0].setAttribute("style", "width:500px; height:200px;");
```

---

```
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "images/image_1.jpg");
    img.setAttribute("style", "width:500px; height:200px;");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `document.querySelectorAll` returns **an element list**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

---

#### FYI

If you use `document.querySelector` instead, you don't need to specify the index because it returns **the first element** within the document that matches the specified selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector